# asyncpg error: "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" in Heroku

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, discord.py, asyncpg

I'm using asyncpg to connect my database in Heroku postgresql, using python:

```
import asyncpg

async def create_db_pool():
   bot.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(dsn="postgres://....", host="....amazonaws.com", user="xxx", database="yyy", port="5432", password="12345")
```

it was working perfectly until I received an email from heroku advising me of a maintenance: 
 `Maintenance (DATABASE_URL on myappname) is starting now. We will update you when it has completed.`

then this error appeared:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidAuthorizationSpecificationError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "123.456.789.10", user "xxx", database "yyy", SSL off
```

I tried to follow some help, like putting `ssl=True`
but this error appeared:

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

same as putting `ssl="allow"`

```
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidPasswordError: password authentication failed for user "xxx"
```

what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried some of the solutions proposed in [this](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/238) issue?

Comment: yes I tried and didn't work theses solutions

Comment: Can you connect successfully using `psql` or `psycopg2`?

Comment: with psycopg2 yes, but didn't work with asyncpg, still the same error

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution from [this](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/issues/238#issuecomment-355147662) worked.

```py
import ssl
ssl_object = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_object.check_hostname = False
ssl_object.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
# connect elsewhere
pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(uri, ssl=ssl_object)
```

Note: You don't need to use any certificate like mentioned in the comment, as we set verify_mode to not use certificates.